# Fibonacci series in C++ can't get more than 47 numbers

Tags: c++, fibonacci

I designed this program that can print the Fibonacci Series (`series[i] = series[i-1] + series[i-2]`) but i can't get more than 47 numbers because the 48th they become negative and strange numbers (i think this happens when the list is out of range or the item is null):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int length;
    string again = "";
    do {
        cout << "Enter the length you want in your sequence: ";
        cin >> length;
        vector<int> series(length);
        for (int n=0; n<=1; n++) series[n] = n;
        for (int number=2; number<=length; number++) {
            series[number] = series[number-1] + series[number-2];
        }
        for (int i=0; i<length; i++) cout << series[i] << " ";
        cout << endl << "Do it again ? <y/n> ";
        cin >> again;
        cout << endl;
    } while (again == "y");
}
```

**EDIT:**

"Improved" code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::vector<int> fibonacci (int length)
{
    std::vector<int> series(length);
    series[0] = 0;
    series[1] = 1;
    for (int num=2; num<length; num++) {
        series[num] = series[num-1] + series[num-2];
    }
    return series;
}

int main ()
{
    std::string again;
    do {
        std::cout << "Enter how many numbers you want in your series: ";
        int length;
        std::cin >> length;
        std::vector<int> series(length);
        series = fibonacci(length);
        for (int n=0; n<length; n++) std::cout << series[n] << " ";
        std::cout << "\nDo it again <y/n> ? ";
        std::cin >> again;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    } while (again == "y");
}
```

Comment: Change your "int" to "long unsigned int" to allow 64 bits of Fibonacci result rather than 32.

Comment: `int` is too small for the result. Use `long` or even better `long long`

Comment: If you want to go really far, you might consider sacrificing some precision and using a `double`. In that case you can also use O(1) formulas for the fibonacci series.

Comment: You're hitting the limit for the 32-bit int datatype. The limit is going to be there no matter what, even with the `long long` datatype; impose a limit on the `length`, validate the input and fail if it's too large.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but in this for loop `for(int number=2; number<=length; number++)` the index goes out of range at the end.

Comment: Aren't you walking off the end of the vector on your last iteration? You're indexing from `0` to `length` inclusively, so you're storing `length+1` values in your vector.

Comment: Actually I was beyond the vector, but that didn't solve my problem... I tried `long unsigned length;` and `long long length` but neither worked for me. I'm on a 32-bit cpu, that changes something ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you get to the 47th value, the numbers go out of `int` range. The maximum `int` value is `2,147,483,647` and the 46th number is just below at `1,836,311,903`. The 47th number exceeds the maximum with `2,971,215,073`.

Also, as LeonardBlunderbuss mentioned, you are exceeding the range of the vector with the `for` loop that you have. Vectors start with `0`, and so by having `number<=length;` the `range+1` element will be called. The range only goes up to `length-1`.

Answer (score 4):

You are encountering integer overflow, meaning that you are trying to calculate a number that is outsize of the bounds of `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN`. In the case of an unsigned number, it just overflows to zero and starts over, while in the case of a signed integer, it rolls over to `INT_MIN`. In both cases this is referred to as integer overflow or integer wraparound.

You could put a band-aid on the solution by using `long long int` (likely 64-bits on most modern systems) instead of `int` for your primitive data type, or you could use a better approach like a library that supports (almost) arbitrarily long data types, like `libBigInteger`.

**References**

1. *Integer Overflow*, Accessed 2014-03-04, `<http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow>`
2. *C++ Big Integer Library*, Accessed 2014-03-04, `<https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/>`
3. *The limits.h Header File*, Accessed 2014-03-04, `<http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/limits.html>`

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to calculating BIG fibonacci numbers

```
// Study for algorithm that counts n:th fibonacci number                        

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp"

#define get_buffer(a) buffer[(a)%2]
#define BIG boost::multiprecision::cpp_int

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  // atoi returns 0 if not integer                                              
  if(argc != 2 || atoi(argv[1]) < 1){
    std::cout << "You must provide one argument. Integer > 0" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }

  // ring buffer to store previous two fibonacci number, index it with  [i%2]   
  // use defined function get_buffer(i), it will do the magic for you           
  BIG buffer[2]={ 1, 1 };

  // n:th Fibonacci                                                             
  unsigned int fn = atoi(argv[1]);

  // count loop is used if seeked fibonacci number is gt 2                      
  if(fn > 2){
    for(unsigned int i = 2; i < fn; ++i){                                       
      get_buffer(i) = get_buffer(i-1) + get_buffer(i-2);
      // get_buffer(i-1) + get_buffer(i-2) == buffer[0] + buffer[1]
      // if you want to print out every result, do it here
    }
  }

  // Result will be send to cout                                                
  std::cout << "Fibonacci[" << fn << "] is " << get_buffer(fn-1) << std::endl;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```