# Why does this C++ fibonacci sequence program work for the first 46 terms but then start giving seemingly random numbers after that?

Tags: c++, fibonacci

This code returns the correct Fibonacci terms at first but then when it gets to the 47th term it starts giving negative numbers or seemingly random numbers

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x;
    int t1 = 0;
    int t2 = 1;
    int nextTerm = 0;
    cout<< "Enter the term in the sequence that you want:\n";
    cin>> x;

    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        if (i == 1) {
            cout<< t1 << ", ";
            continue;
        }

        if (i == 2) {
            cout<< t2 << ", ";
            continue;
        }
        nextTerm = t1 + t2;
        t1 = t2;
        t2 = nextTerm;

        cout<< nextTerm << ", ";

    }
    cout<< "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

And this is what it returns:

[image]

If anyone could explain why this is please answer, also I recently started learning C++ so please go easy on me in the comments :)

Comment: integer overflow. Use a bigger integer type or a bigint library. Note also that signed integer overflow is UB.

Comment: The maximum number representable by a 32-bit integer (which `int` is on many platforms) is 2^31-1, or 2147483647.

Comment: Ohhh, thank you jaggedSpire! I'll go research that now :)

Comment: Weird. I can't find a good dupe target, even though this question gets asked pretty frequently. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645193) has a good question/answer pair, but is more on the topic of direct calculation instead of iterative, and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185259/) has more wrong than an integer overflow...

Comment: Alternative duplicate, [Why am i not able to print 47th fibonacci number correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38300063/364696).

Comment: And a C++ specific one: [Fibonacci series in C++ can't get more than 47 numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22185259/364696)

Comment: Thank you guys! This really helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Built-in numeric types in c++ have a fixed range of values they can represent. What happens when signed integer like `int` exceed this range (oveflow) is undefined. Often you will notice that they wrap around to there smallest possible representable value, but don't count on it. See [std::numeric_limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) for more information. Note that the range of values depends on your platform and compiler.

The type `intmax_t` defined in the cstdint header will provide you with your platform's largest integer type.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked how big your integer is? The c++ int can hold only integers of certain size and when you add more to it it overflows (it is modular arithmetic just like analog clock: if it is 10 o'clock and you wait four hours it is 2 o'clock). So a very big number + something = very small number (usually).

```
F_47 = 2971215073
```

Check this out: [How would you set a variable to the largest number possible in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273913/how-would-you-set-a-variable-to-the-largest-number-possible-in-c)

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained why this is causing the problem (I have already upvoted as I believe you are correct, but it would be helpful if you explained why the OP needs to check the size of `int`).

Answer (score 0):

you can have only numbers less than or equal to `2^31-1` that is **approximately** around `10^9` , so when the number exceeds , it will gonna be a negative number
if you use `long long` instead of `int` the range of numbers you can see becomes greater